# How to insert value from gridview into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have two tables in a SQL Server database. I select from table `ADMS` and I need to insert master table by gridview but I dont know how to insert with gridview. Please help. I've tried for many days and I did not pass yet

```
protected void Button3_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButton2.Checked)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        // con.Open(); // don't need the Open, the Fill will open and close the connection automatically
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ADMS_Machining where datetime='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        mytable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(mytable);
        GridView2.DataSource = mytable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        // con.Open(); // don't need the Open, the Fill will open and close the connection automatically
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Machining_Master where datetime='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
        mytable = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(mytable);
        GridView2.DataSource = mytable;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    String strConnString, strSQL;

    strConnString = "Server=kane-pc;UID=sa;PASSWORD=1234;Database=Machining;Max Pool Size=400;Connect Timeout=600;";
   //here

   conn.ConnectionString = conn;
   conn.Open();
   cmd.Connection = conn;
   cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
}
```

Comment: don't forget to accept as answer if it works for you @kanesmith

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract values from a grid view depending on what you have placed in the cells...

```
string value = this.GridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

You can also track the selected row event, and get specific controls like the following...

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    string someValueTakenFromLabel = (GridView2.SelectedRow.FindControl("lblAnyLabelHere") as Label).Text;

    // .... do something with value here
}
```

I suggest you go through some tutorials though to get the hang of how to use GridView.

- http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/building-20-applications/lesson-8-working-with-the-gridview-and-formview
- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-get-Selected-Row-cell-value-from-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: how i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

You have to first read data from cells and then insert them into database using SqlCommand. 
Assuming that you have M_ID and M_NAME columns in your Machining_Master table you can insert values to database as below:

```
//Assuming that your id column is first column and name is second column
//get value of id and name
int mId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
string mName = GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

string connectionStrng = "your connection string";
string insertSql = "INSERT INTO Machining_Master (M_ID, M_NAME) VALUES (@mId, @mName)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStrng))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertSql, conn))
    {
        try
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("mId", mId));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("mName", mName));

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close connection
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have error {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Double DailyMean = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
            Double Process_Mean = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
            Double Long_Term_Stdev = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
            Double CPK_ESTIMATE = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text);
            Double DAILY_MINIMUM = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text);
            Double DAILY_MAXIMUM = Convert.ToDouble(GridView2.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text);

Comment: have you selected a row?